# Javascript rotation animation after a certain interval

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm a beginner in js and am trying to build a snake game. I need to move the snake blocks one after another after some interval but the blocks need to be connected to each other without separating when animating.

Code:

```
function rotate() {
 var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
 [].forEach.call(blocks, function(block, i) {
  setTimeout(function(){  
   block.style.transition= '-webkit-transform .3s linear';
   block.style.transform='translate(350px)'
  },i*30);
 });
}

document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click',rotate);
```

Style.css:

```
.block {
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
background: grey;
border-radius: 50%;  
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="block" id="block1"></div>
    <div class="block" id="block2"></div>
    <div class="block" id="block3"></div>
    <div class="block" id="block4"></div>
```

Comment: Where are the dots trying to go?

Comment: Those dots need to move in a certain x position along mouse cursor. But they are separating from each other. I need them to stay connected even in the motion.